# JUnit Tests in IntelliJ 2017 - is my package structure incorrect?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, package

I am brushing up on my Java development skills. I am currently trying to run some JUnit tests in IntelliJ 2017. I am unable to run any kind of tests, currently. Does my test structure have something to do with it? I have tried looking at multiple resources, but none of them seem to confirm what the exact test structure should be.

Here is my current structure:

```
[A] src
    [1] com.company
        [a] Main
        [b] Triangle
    [2] test
        [a] TriangleTest
```

Does this look correct?

Comment: Tests should be normally placed under a test source root which is not under the source root as your main code. Or the tests can reside in a separate module. [See here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html).

Comment: What is the error and how are you trying to run the tests? If you use maven (for example), it will expect a test source path by default. If you just want to run them from idea, place them wherever you want in the project but not in the source code folder.

Comment: You should show the test class.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-test-driven-development.html

Comment: Thank you, all. These were very helpful to me and I was able to understand where to put my test classes.